# Attach debugger in C# to another process

Tags: c#, debugging

I'd like to be able to automatically attach a debugger, something like:  `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`, except rather than the current process to another named process. I've got a process name and PID to identify the other process.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422768/attaching-to-a-child-process-automatically-in-visual-studio-during-debugging

Comment: @GSerjo is that a Visual Studio macro? What is DTE?

Comment: Yes, it's macro.  DTE object represents the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE) and is the highest level object in the automation model hierarchy

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit:** 
[`GSerjo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812430/1106367) offered the correct solution. I'd like to share a few thoughts on how to improve it (and an explanation). I hope my improved answer will be useful to to others who experience the same problem.

---

## Attaching the VS Debugger to a Process

### Manually

1. Open the Windows Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>).
2. Go to the Tab `Processes`.
3. Right click the process.
4. Select `Debug`.

Or, within Visual Studio, select `Debug > Attach to Process...`.

Results will vary depending on whether you have access to the source code.

### Automatically with C#

> A **note of caution:** The following code is brittle in the sense that certain values, 
>   such as the Visual Studio Version number, are hard-coded. Keep this in mind going forward 
>   if you are planning to distribute your program.

First of all, add a reference to EnvDTE to your project (right click on the references folder in the solution explorer, add reference). In the following code, I'll only show the unusual using directives; the normal ones such as `using System` are omitted.

Because you are [interacting with COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx#sectionToggle2) you need to make sure to decorate your `Main` method (the entry point of your application) with the [`STAThreadAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx).

Then, you need to [define the `IOleMessageFilter` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.100).aspx#exampleToggle) that will allow you to interact with the defined COM methods (note the [`ComImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comimportattribute.aspx)). We need to access the message filter so we can retry if the Visual Studio COM component blocks one of our calls.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComImport, Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleMessageFilter
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo);

    [PreserveSig]
    int RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType);

    [PreserveSig]
    int MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType);
}
```

Now, we need to implement this interface in order to handle incoming messages:

```
public class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
{
    private const int Handled = 0, RetryAllowed = 2, Retry = 99, Cancel = -1, WaitAndDispatch = 2;

    int IOleMessageFilter.HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo)
    {
        return Handled;
    }

    int IOleMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType)
    {
        return dwRejectType == RetryAllowed ? Retry : Cancel;
    }

    int IOleMessageFilter.MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType)
    {
        return WaitAndDispatch;
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(new MessageFilter());
    }

    public static void Revoke()
    {
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(null);
    }

    private static void CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter)
    {
        IOleMessageFilter oldFilter;
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(newFilter, out oldFilter);
    }

    [DllImport("Ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter, out IOleMessageFilter oldFilter);
}
```

I defined the return values as constants for better readability and refactored the whole thing a bit to get rid of some of the duplication from the MSDN example, so I hope you'll find it self-explanatory. `extern int CoRegisterMessageFilter` is our connection to the unmanaged message filter code - you can [read up on the extern keyword at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5(v=vs.100).aspx).

Now all that's left is some code illustrating the usage:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE;

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    MessageFilter.Register();
    var process = GetProcess(7532);
    if (process != null)
    {
        process.Attach();
        Console.WriteLine("Attached to {0}", process.Name);
    }
    MessageFilter.Revoke();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Process GetProcess(int processID)
{
    var dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
    var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.OfType<Process>();
    return processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProcessID == processID);
}
```

Comment: No, that's not what I need. Like I said, I want an equivalent of Debugger.Launch except for another process.

Comment: It seems he wants to do it programmatically however.

Comment: @DaveHillier What would be the difference between C# and plain Task Manager?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I've got a number of services to manage. It's useful to me to be able to deploy and then subsequently debug from a management app. I've already got the services to install, stop and start.

Comment: The same problem "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)". COM is very sensitive, so added [STAThread], then Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED) is appeared. Looks like solution is here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @DaveHillier I gave it another try, and now it works for me. I added an explanation while I was at it, though you've probably figured it out in the meantime.

Comment: Works really nicely - bump the ProgId to 11 for VS2012

Comment: +1 This can be used in conjunction with Process.Start() and Debugger.IsAttached in the spawning process! Great work.

Comment: If i debug the phase of debugging attachment it work.
But if i try to run till i placed the breakpoint i get RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED 0x80010001

Comment: @codesparkle Worked great!! Thanks. +1 for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 13):

Check this out

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ForTest
    {
        [STAThread]  
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var dte = (DTE) Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
            MessageFilter.Register();

            IEnumerable<Process> processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.OfType<Process>();
            var process = processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProcessID == 6152);
            if (process != null)
            {
                process.Attach();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
    {
        //
        // Class containing the IOleMessageFilter
        // thread error-handling functions.

        // Start the filter.

        //
        // IOleMessageFilter functions.
        // Handle incoming thread requests.

        #region IOleMessageFilter Members

        int IOleMessageFilter.HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType,
                                                 IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr
                                                                                          lpInterfaceInfo)
        {
            //Return the flag SERVERCALL_ISHANDLED.
            return 0;
        }

        // Thread call was rejected, so try again.
        int IOleMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr
                                                    hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType)
        {
            if (dwRejectType == 2)
            // flag = SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER.
            {
                // Retry the thread call immediately if return >=0 & 
                // <100.
                return 99;
            }
            // Too busy; cancel call.
            return -1;
        }

        int IOleMessageFilter.MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee,
                                             int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType)
        {
            //Return the flag PENDINGMSG_WAITDEFPROCESS.
            return 2;
        }

        #endregion

        public static void Register()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter newFilter = new MessageFilter();
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            CoRegisterMessageFilter(newFilter, out oldFilter);
        }

        // Done with the filter, close it.
        public static void Revoke()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            CoRegisterMessageFilter(null, out oldFilter);
        }

        // Implement the IOleMessageFilter interface.
        [DllImport("Ole32.dll")]
        private static extern int
            CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter, out
                                                                     IOleMessageFilter oldFilter);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IOleMessageFilter
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int HandleInComingCall(
            int dwCallType,
            IntPtr hTaskCaller,
            int dwTickCount,
            IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo);

        [PreserveSig]
        int RetryRejectedCall(
            IntPtr hTaskCallee,
            int dwTickCount,
            int dwRejectType);

        [PreserveSig]
        int MessagePending(
            IntPtr hTaskCallee,
            int dwTickCount,
            int dwPendingType);
    }
}
```

- [How to: Create and Attach to Another Instance of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cefss65.aspx)
- [How to: Fix 'Application is Busy' and 'Call was Rejected By Callee'
  Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The [`STAThread Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx#remarksToggle) is *useless* on all methods except the entry point (probably `Main`).

Comment: Duuuuude. Where were you :)

Comment: @Emad, always here, even when I'm there, I'm still here :)

Answer (score 9):

Simpler way of doing it.

```
public static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
        {
            var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
            foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf("YourProcess.exe") != -1))
                proc.Attach();
        }

        internal static DTE2 GetCurrent()
        {
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0"); // For VisualStudio 2013

            return dte2;
        }
```

Usage:

```
Attach(GetCurrent());
```

Comment: Where do you get the DTE2 and EnvDTE definitions from?

Comment: You need to add reference to EnvDTE80 (References > Add references > Assemblies > Framework) and then use it in your class

`using EnvDTE80;`

Comment: Apparently, it requires both EnvDTE80 and EnvDTE and these are located in References > Add references > Assemblies > Extensions (at least in VS2017). Not sure what version number to use, as "VisualStudio.DTE.14.0" fails with a `Invalid class string` exception.

Comment: I am using VS2013 so can't help on that but this [post](https://www.helixoft.com/blog/creating-envdte-dte-for-vs-2017-from-outside-of-the-devenv-exe.html) may help. Good luck.

Comment: So it was 15.0, not 14.0. Worked like a charm.

Comment: One problem I've stumbled upon so far: `Marshal.GetActiveObject` returns a reference to the first opened VS instance rather than the _active_ one.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to run; `vsjitdebugger.exe -p ProcessId`

It may be possible to use `Process.Start` to do this within a c# app.

Comment: This runs a new instance of visual studio.

Comment: You can select an existing instance or use a new one

Answer (score 1):

If you have troubles with attaching debugger to process that is too quick to attach manually, don't forget you can sometimes add `Console.ReadKey();` to a first line of your code and then you have all the time you need to attach it manually. Surprisingly it took me a while to figure that one out :D