# C# Attach Debugger to Another Process in Code at Runtime

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging

I have wcf console application server and console application client.

I would like to attach a debugger to the WCF server if the client is in debug mode in order to debug the server services.

So the client would run this code on startup:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Debugger.AttachToProcess("WCFProcessName"); //<<How this is done
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: `Tools -> Attach to Process` or simply `ctrl + alt + p` in VS

Comment: @Leri As the question suggested I would like to do it in code - I would fix the title

Comment: @YoYo I am really confused now. Do you want WCF service to start debugging itself?

Comment: @Leri - I fixed the question - I would like the client attach a debugger to the WCF service if the client has debugger attached

Comment: See answer to this question: [Attach debugger in C# to another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811856/attach-debugger-in-c-sharp-to-another-process)

Comment: @Shad as the Comments in the post you suggested reply this does not the solution for in Code Attachment of debugger to another process

Comment: @YoYo, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811856/attach-debugger-in-c-sharp-to-another-process#answer-11811881) describes hot to attach debugger to process from C# code.