# dotnet core 2.0 - programmatically attach the VS2017 debugger to a process

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-standard

In my dotnet core 2.0 application I re-launch the same application in a different process (with some different arguments) at a certain point. I want to be able to programmatically attach the current Visual Studio (2017) debugger to the new process.

[Here is an example of how it is done in full framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023147/183271) but for starters the `Marshal.GetActiveObject` method doesn't appear to exist.

Is there a different way to achieve this in dotnet core 2.0? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: It doesn't help solve your problem in the long term, but `Mashal.GetActiveObject` doesn't exist in .NET Core, because it is a [.NET Framework, Xamarin and Mono specific API](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String)) - presumably because it makes Windows specific API calls under the hood.

Comment: Yeh I figured as much - just wondered if there is a different way or maybe a nuget package I can bring in. Already checked the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility)

Comment: If you need to use .NET Framework APIs, change the application so that it uses .NET Framework.

Answer (score 5):

While this is changing, .Net Core was envisioned to be as cross-platform as possible and originally left out many 'windows-only' methods. That said, you can still call into the underlying windows functions using P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("oleaut32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
static extern void GetActiveObject(ref Guid rclsid, IntPtr pvReserved,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppunk);

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CLSIDFromProgID(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszProgID, out Guid pclsid);
....

// Replace XX with the correct version
CLSIDFromProgID($"VisualStudio.DTE.XX.0", out var classId); 
GetActiveObject(ref classId, default, out dte);
```