# Attach debugger to running process from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

In my project I use `Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);` to load dll from other local project at the runtime (reasons for that don't matter). Is it somehow possible from code, to open new instance of visual studio (with project from dll) and after that attach debugger to the process that is already running?

Comment: The odds that "no" is the correct answer are about as good as you having picked the wrong Assembly.Load method.  Only one debugger can be attached to a process.  So use the one you're already using.  Equal odds for you favoring Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "just my code" unticked.

Comment: Here is a related thread that maybe can help you.[Attach debugger in C# to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811856/attach-debugger-in-c-sharp-to-another-process).

Comment: Thanks @KyleWang, i was looking for something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Debugger.Launch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netcore-3.1). It should open "Choose Just-In-Time Debugger" dialog like this (at least if debugger is not already attached):

[image]

Comment: the project to which i was trying to attach debbuger was library, so it had no entry point in which  i could add Debbuger.Lanuch.