# How to run current project by visual studio extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a console application which generates json.

I need to execute this application by using a Visual Studio extension (Vsix). For that I created a VSix project with command. When I click run command, I need to run the current project.

I have no idea how to do that.

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here is my method which is executed when i click it on menu
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356565/how-to-start-a-single-project-without-debugging-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try these:

```
using EnvDTE;

..........


DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;

dte.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Start");
```

To run the application without debug, you can try this:

```
 dte.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StartWithoutDebugging");
```

And it will debug the current active project when you click the button.

More info, you can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135391/start-debugging-specific-project-programmatically-using-envdte-executecommand).

=========================================

**And** also you could try to use this:

```
dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The solution working for me was using Dte but dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Run();

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I will add it:) Anyway, have a nice day~